# Ignore 'cannot remove `dir`: Is a directory message

Tags: directory, rm, deleted-files

I'm setting up an automation process where I am deleting files in a directory which contains sub-directories.  I only want to delete the files in the directory, and want to keep the sub-directories intact.  So right now I am just using `rm *` to delete the files in that directory.  However, this command throws the message: `cannt remove 'dir': Is a directory`.  I know I'm being knit-picky, but I don't want that message to repeatedly appear in my logs.  Is there a better command I can use for deletion or a way that I can tell `rm` to ignore the sub-directories?

Comment: `find somedir -type f -exec rm {} \;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just throw away the error messages:

```
rm * 2>/dev/null
```

That'll throw away all errors. If you want to see other potential errors then we can do something more complicated:

```
rm * 2>&1 | grep -v 'cannot remove .*: Is a directory'
```

In this way other errors will still be logged.

Comment: Question says "want to keep the sub-directories intact"...

Answer (score 2):

In zsh:

```
rm *(^/)
```

Other shells have no equivalent to zsh's [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). Instead you can call `find`, which is capable of discriminating files by type, and tell it not to recurse into subdirectories other than `.` (the starting directory).

```
find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o rm -f {} +
```

This deletes dot files, whereas `*` doesn't match dot files. If you want to preserve dot files, tell `find` not to call `rm` on them.

```
find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o ! -name '.*' rm -f {} +
```

(You can use `-mindepth`, `-maxdepth` and `-delete`, but only if you don't need your script to run on systems where `find` doesn't have these options. The options I used are portable.)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
find ./ -type f -exec rm -f * {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

If you want to keep even files in your subdirectories intact:

```
rm -f * 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I thought recursive deletes removed all data in sub-directories as well?

Comment: @requiemforameme Yes it does. Sorry I didn't see  you said only files, You should use: `find /path -type f -exec rm -f * {} \;`

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I am still getting the message.  Am I just being too picky?

Comment: Remove the star from FarazX's comment.  Or just use `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: @requiemforameme No mate not at all. I updated my answer, just do that and that won't show you any error.

Comment: Won't that still delete files from subdirectories?  The question said it wanted sub-dirs untouched.  And isn't the `*` redundant?

Comment: @StephenHarris I thought that so, but it seems he wants them to be removed. He just want to get rid of errors. I have no idea.

Comment: @requiemforameme Hey mate, read what Stephen Harris said, if you want your files in subdirectories intact, you should just use `rm -f * 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: @FarazX All 3 commands work.  I've tested them all out.

Comment: @requiemforameme Alright, so good luck mate.